# jquery cycle with previous and next previews

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I have created a slideshow using the jquery cycle plugin with previous and next buttons. What i am trying to do is when the user hovers the previous or the next button to get a tooltip with a preview of the previous or the next image respectively. Any ideas on how to achive something like that?

Answer (score 1):

For the tooltip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

For the next/previous image, you'll need to keep the data somewhere before showing it - like a hidden div. Qtip takes a 'content' parameter that you can populate with inner-html from any element on the page using jQuery(selector).html().

I.E:

```
jQuery(next_button_selector).qtip(
 {
   content:{ 
     text: jQuery(hidden_div_that_wraps_image_selector).html()
   }
 });
```

Comment: Well i guess that's the easy part, what i don't know is how to select the previous and next image at any point in the slideshow and keep it somewhere

Comment: Depends on your slideshow. Read the docs on it. See if they've got any kind of callback, something you can hook into. Otherwise they'll usually do something like set a url fragment (index.html#fragment), or stash data in some attribute. 

Other times it's a progressive enhancement thing (turn this boring <li> into a gallery, using the nested images as the gallery images). In which case, with jQuery, you'll simply need to traverse around (next(), prev(), closest() ... etc) accordingly.

Comment: To help with all of this, make sure you have Firebug installed. If you  enable the script debugger, you can actually watch how the gallery behaves when **it** needs to figure out what the next image is going to be. You can then copy it, or maybe learn something along the way like:
"Oh, right before it opens the next image, it triggers an event which I have to listen for jQuery(document).bind('onNextImage',function(evt,data){ ... }); And it gives me the url I'm looking for!"

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery carousel plugin [Hero-Carousel](http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/)